# Obtaining all instances of a specific field from json in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a webservice that returns a very large json object. I decode this to an array for parsing.

What I'm trying to do though is extract all array members from the json array where there is [id] => 21 at the start of the individual array object.

A nice simple task using LINQ, but not an idea how to do this in PHP. There has to be a way to filter through and extract.

Comment: Add code with existing attempt :D

Comment: And a non critical exemple of the json returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use something like `array_filter` for this

```
function find_id($var)
{
    // returns whether the is is 21
    return($var['id'] === 21);
}


$result = array_filter($jsondata, "find_id"));
```

**array_filter** *Iterates over each value in the array passing them to the callback function. If the callback function returns true, the current value from array is returned into the result array. Array keys are preserved.*

Comment: That's perfect. Is there a way to specify the filter value instead of having it hard coded? I'd rather not have to use a $GLOBAL[...] if I can get away with it.

Comment: Something like this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#93965 ??

Comment: Or use `array_walk` which can receive a parameter